# Register objects for google tango fails with latest Unity sdk

Tags: google-project-tango

m_tangoApplication.Register(this); gives nullreference exception in TangoArScreen and in MarkerDetectionUIController and the application doesnt start. I am using Unity 5.3, samsung s8 and the Marker detection scene given in the Unity sdk (latest sdk, Ikariotikos) but doesnt work, just stays in the Unity splash screen

Comment: You will need to share some of your code in the question.

Comment: It is the code that google tango package for Unity gives, the Start method is        m_camera = GetComponent<Camera>();
        m_tangoApplication = FindObjectOfType<TangoApplication>();
        m_arCameraPostProcess = gameObject.GetComponent<ARCameraPostProcess>();

        if (m_tangoApplication != null)
        {
            m_tangoApplication.OnDisplayChanged += _OnDisplayChanged;
            m_tangoApplication.Register(this);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on a Samsung S8?
That's not a Tango Device, you need to use ARCore, which is different  (:

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to use the Virtual Positioning Service with ARCore?

Comment: No worries (: The Visual Positioning Service is in closed beta.  I would recommend staying away from it until it is released properly.
Also, I have not heard of any VPS stuff on ARCore yet, only Tango.  It is a safe bet that ARCore will be the platform that VPS is initially launched on, but it might not be do-able yet.

If you do want to try VPS, you'd need to get onto the closed beta: https://developers.google.com/tango/overview/concepts#visual_positioning_service_overview

My strong advice however is to stick to pure ARCore for now